# OnMarkerDragListener for Marker Position along associated circles Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on an application in which I have two markers one for source and one for destination and there are two circles associated with them.OnMarkerDragListener Listener I am able to drag the markers but how may I deal with the particular circle to shift along the marker. as there is OnMarkerDragListener Listener for both the markers.How I may be able to know which marker out of source and destination has moved so to remove particular circle associated with it without removing the circle of the other marker.

```
 Marker sourceMarker;
 Marker destinationMarker;


Circle srcCircle; //circle associated with sourceMarker
Circle destCircle ; // cricle associated with destinationMarker
. .  . 
. . .
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(SourceDestinationActivity.this);
                    List<Address> list = null;
                    LatLng ll = marker.getPosition();
                    try {
                        list = gc.getFromLocation(ll.latitude, ll.longitude, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                    Address add = list.get(0);
                    marker.setTitle(add.getLocality());
                    marker.setSnippet(add.getCountryName());
                    marker.showInfoWindow();


                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }

 . . . . .
 . . . . . 

private Circle drawCircle(LatLng ll,int range){
        Toast.makeText(this, "circle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        CircleOptions options = new CircleOptions().center(ll).radius(range).fillColor(0x98e698).strokeColor(0x1e7b1e);
        return mMap.addCircle(options);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for the [onMarkerDrag](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener.html#onMarkerDrag(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker)).  You will need to keep a member variable of the marker and do an equality check against the `marker` that is being dragged.

Comment: all I wanted to know is `public abstract void onMarkerDragEnd (Marker marker)` is there any way to identify which markers out of both the marker is dragged as there is a single listener for both markers how to identify the marker passed as a parameter is the source or destination marker.

Comment: @FaisalNaseer  The listener is attached to the map.  That `marker` parameter is the marker that is being dragged.   When you add your 'source' and 'destination' markers to the map keep a copy of them as member variables and compare it to that parameter.